# What is the difference between starting Ignite using run.sh script inside docker image and using Ignition.Start() method?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, ignite, gridgain

I know two ways to start Ignite cluster - one is running it as a docker container using run.sh script inside apacheignite/ignite image and the other is by running Ignition.Start() method inside the app, which allows us to have thick client ready to work on Ignite.

We would like to use the thick client so the second approach is good to go, but for now we've been using the first approach.

The question is - does someone know if both methods result in the same cluster configuration? Do they differ in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Internally `ignite.sh` or `run.sh` just invoke `Ignition.start()` after all. But before that, it performs additional steps by configuring JVM instance, setting up IGNITE_HOME,  picking up your configuration, making verifications, handling the arguments, exit codes, etc.

It's totally fine to start a thick client node programmatically from within your user application.